# any new firefox 3.5.X security improvements that'd prevent access "chrome://" uri paths in markup?

Tags: security, unit-testing, firefox, selenium, jsunit

A little context:

I'm trying to build and run the unit tests for the source of the Selenium IDE plugin.  Everything builds correctly (through maven commands, et al) and the unit tests fire up an instance of Firefox.  However, the jsUnit testRunner.html page freezes whenever a `chrome://`-accessed uri path is encountered.

I realize there are a LOT of moving parts in this situation, but I'm fairly certain/convinced that it's centered on an inability to access `chrome://` paths within the markup of testRunner.html.

I am working with:

- Firefox 3.5.7
- Selenium IDE 1.0.3 source
- Maven 2.2.1
- Windows XP box

I've already taken into account various known required tweaks for such execution in a Firefox 3.X environment (setting `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy = false` in the profile preferences and adding `contentaccessible=yes` to the chrome.manifest file of selenium-ide), but to no avail.

Does anyone have any insight into such an issue?  I know my specific situation includes building Selenium IDE, but my gut is telling me it's a simple browser security situation.

Any and all insight is much appreciated!